# Enviar mensajes con mi telegram usando python

Tags: python, api, telegram

estoy intentando crear un "programa" con el cual pueda enviar mensajes a telegram a través de python usando mi propia cuenta, el problema es que no encuentro material para hacer lo que necesito, si bien logre hacer que un bot enviara mensajes a los grupos que le indique, no se como hacer que en lugar de bot sea mi cuenta de telegram, que tendria que hacer?

```
import os
import requests

def clean():...
continuar = True
while(continuar):
    clean()
    send = input("Digite su mensaje: ")
    id = "@grupo"
    token = "token de mi bot" #que tendria que poner aqui para permitir acceso a mi cuenta?
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage" #y supongo que aqui cambia lo de "/bot"
    parame = {
        'chat_id': id,
        'text': send
    }
    requests.post(url, params=parame)
    con = input("Presione x si desea salir del programa y s si desea enviar otro: ")
    if con == "x":
        continuar = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo espero que sirva.

En tu archivo `.env`

```
TELEGRAM_TOKEN=TU_tOKEN_AQUÍ
```

#### Instalación

```sh
pip install python-dotenv  # para poder leer los archivos.env
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

> Ahora en tu archivo `main.py`

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler
load_dotenv()
import os


TOKEN_TELEGRAM = os.environ['TELEGRAM_TOKEN']

from telegram import Bot

class BotTelegramMessage():
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.bot=Bot(token)
        # Updater: es el encargado de contestar a los comandos que envíe el usuario.
        self.updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
        # Polling se pone a la espera de que se ingresen comandos
        self.updater.start_polling()
        # Dispatcher: está al pendiente de todas las ventanas donde se encuentra el bot.
        self.dispatcher = self.updater.dispatcher

    def esperar_comando(self, comando, funcion):
        """
        Función que espera que se ingrese en el chat el comando y ejecuta la función que se ingresen como parámetro.
        Parámetros:
            comando: texto que colocará el usuario acompañado de una barra '/' en el chat de Telegram..
                Tipo: (str)
                Ejemplo: 'start'
            funcion: función que se ejecutará cuando el usuario realice determinado comando.
                Tipo: (fn)
        """
        self.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler(comando, funcion))
        

    def start(self, update, context):
        bot = context.bot
        user = update.effective_user
        lastname = update.message.chat.last_name
        if lastname != None:
            nombre = f"{update.message.chat.first_name}  {lastname}"
        else:
            nombre = f"{update.message.chat.first_name}"   
            self.bot.sendMessage(user.id, text = f"¡Hola {nombre}! saludos esto es un mensaje")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot_message = BotTelegramMessage(TOKEN_TELEGRAM)
    bot_message.esperar_comando("start", bot_message.start)
```

#### salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, es una buena forma pero lo que busco en si es poder enviar mensajes de mi cuenta de telegram a otra (o a un grupo) con python, osea ver si es posible

Comment: Lo dudo hermano, en telegram solo es posible por medio de los Bots, saludos.

Comment: ok muchas gracias por la ayuda